# How do I click on this button with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey

I'm a total newbie with JS, and I'm trying to click on this button:

```
<a class="simplebutton" href="javascript:void(0);">find</a>
```

The XPath of this button is: `/html/body/div[5]/div/span[2]/a`, and a snapshot of the target page can be seen at [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yd9TX/).

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work. (I'm using the function `getElementsByClassName` which I got from http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('simplebutton').submit();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a **complete script** that does that. It uses jQuery for [the :contains() selector](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=contains-selector).

**Update:** Modified script to account for reported AJAX.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Click on a specific link
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a major design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.
    It restores the sandbox.
*/

//--- Note that contains() is CASE-SENSITIVE.
waitForKeyElements ("a.simplebutton:contains('follow')", clickOnFollowButton);

function clickOnFollowButton (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

---

Note: in some cases the `contains()` term can trigger falsely.  For example, if there is an `<a class="simplebutton">unfollow</a>` button.
Here's one way to prevent false clicks. Modify the `clickOnFollowButton` function like so:

```
function clickOnFollowButton (jNode) {
    if ( ! /^\s*follow\s*$/i.test (jNode.text() ) ) {
        /*--- If the node contains anything but "follow" (surrounded by 
            optional whitespace), don't click it.
        */
        return false;
    }
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

---

Several things:

1. [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a list or "collection" of elements.  You can't just `.submit()` its result like that. `.submit()` is for single elements.
2. Since this is a link `.submit()` won't work. `.click()` will often work, but often not -- when a link is empowered by an event listener (which must be the case for this question).

   The `clickEvent` code, given above, works in almost all cases.
3. [The page code you gave](http://jsfiddle.net/yd9TX/) does not have any link, with `class="simplebutton"` and text containing `find`!
4. What Browser are you using? Which Greasemonkey version? And what OS?
5. Find and use an appropriate javascript reference and an appropriate DOM reference.  The reference listed in the question is for a *library* that is not standard and not included in your script (most likely).

   - The [MDN JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference) is the most up-to-date and the most applicable for Greasemonkey (a *Firefox* extension) applications.
   - Likewise, the [MDN Document Object Model (DOM) Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM).
6. Use the CSS path, its much easier than XPATH, for this kind of thing. Firebug will show you the CSS path for a given element.
   jQuery uses CSS selectors/paths, as does `document.querySelector()` (a non jQuery approach).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I really appreciate. Sadly your code doesn't work as expected. For sure it's my fault because I'm giving wrong informations since I'm not an expert. In my opinion the button I want to click is loaded after the initial page has been loaded so GM can't identify it.
If you have an instagram account you can log in in this site: http://ink361.com, I'd want to click the follow button.

Comment: That's a pretty big omission.  You should probably upvote both answers to compensate.  Anyway, I don't have an instagram account, but I changed the script to where it works with AJAX. It will fire no matter when that button appears.  Just make sure it's `follow` and not `Follow` (case is critical for that).

Comment: Thanks for your support man! Now it's working as expected: sorry if my question wasn't as complete as it should be!

Comment: Just another quick question here: I have waitForKeyElements ("a.simplebutton:contains('follow')", clickOnFollowButton);.
This will fire if the word 'follow' is contained, however this will fire also for the word 'unfollow'. How to make it fire only in the first case?

Comment: Updated the answer to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the method [`click`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361) rather than `submit`. You can use [`submit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357) when you want to submit a form.

`getElementsByClassName` also returns an array of elements, you need to retrieve the one you want and then call `click` on it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('simplebutton')[0].click();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLDde/

Comment: @Giorgio Forgot about selecting an element from the array. You can't click an generic data structure, but you can click an HtmlElement.

Comment: `.click()` does not working everywhere, since you already caught the event, why you need call `submit()`?

Comment: Now I'm using: document.getElementsByClassName('simplebutton')[0].click();

But still not clicking

Comment: @Giorgio Did you try the jsfiddle? In your example in the question nothing should happen when the link is clicked (you've disabled that by adding href="javascript:void(0);"). There might be cross-browser issues, what browser are you using?

Comment: Maybe the content of the page is loaded dinamically with ajax?

Comment: Yes, it's working in Jsfiddle but not in the original website.

Comment: @Giorgio Can you link to an example or create a jsfiddle? When is the code that clicks the link run? It needs to be after the link has been placed on the page.

Comment: Can't we use the xpath instead? I don't know if that class name is the first occurrence in the page...

Comment: @Giorgio I thought finding the element was not the problem. Can you create a jsfiddle so that I can have a look?

Comment: @Giorgio Just the parts needed to replicate the problem.

Comment: The part needed is here: /html/body/div[5]/div/span[2]/a