# Click <select> and <input> after page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am writing a Greasemonkey script to interact with orders on Shipstation.com.

The script will select certain values in `<select>` and `<input>` elements of the order modal based on certain criteria.

Thus, the script must be able to interact with these elements.

However, I cannot figure out how to do so.

So far, I have tried to do the following and have been unable to trigger a click on the element:

- Set the value of the element using JS `.value`
- Set the value of the element using jQuery `.val`
- Trigger a click event on the element using JS `.click()`
- Trigger a click event on the element using this code:

```
function triggerMostButtons (jNode) {
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode, "click");
}

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

triggerMostButtons(jNode);
```

It appears that Shipstation is locking the value of `<select>` and `<input>` values.

Here are examples of the SO questions I have read to try and figure this out. I haven't been able to trigger a click on these elements using any of these approaches:

- ["Normal" button-clicking approaches are not working in Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511381/normal-button-clicking-approaches-are-not-working-in-greasemonkey-script)
- [How to simulate click in react app using tampermonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480918/how-to-simulate-click-in-react-app-using-tampermonkey)
- [Greasemonkey script to automatically select, and click, a specific button with non-English characters in the value/selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951746/greasemonkey-script-to-automatically-select-and-click-a-specific-button-with-n)
- [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)
- [Simulating a mousedown, click, mouseup sequence in Tampermonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025165/simulating-a-mousedown-click-mouseup-sequence-in-tampermonkey)
- [javascript click a value in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563911/javascript-click-a-value-in-dropdown-list)
- [How to change a <select> value from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490906/how-to-change-a-select-value-from-javascript)
- [How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)
- [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

How else can I trigger a click on these elements?

Alternatively, how can I set the value of these fields using JS? Do I have to find the data model in the JS and edit the value directly? Or find a way to hijack the functions that are triggered when a user clicks on these elements?

[image]

Comment: there are no `<select>` on Shipstation.com

Comment: @Sean, Can you create small fiddle with your issue? otherwise setting `<select>` values should be simple `document.getElementById('selectIdHere').value = "myValue"`;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the values are loaded dynamically from the server, so you need to wait until the full page is loaded by adding a `load event`.

Then grab the `select` elements by a `document.getElementById` (or `querySelector`) and set your desired value (If I understood correctly, you don't need a click event).

You didn't provide an example I can work with, but I tried it with this `https://www.shipstation.com/step1/`
Notice how after the page loads, the country will be set to Canada:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 933923
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @match *://*.shipstation.com/*
// ==/UserScript==


window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  
  document.getElementById('country').value = "CA";
  document.getElementById('howdidyouhearaboutus').value = "Banner Ad";
  
});
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear - the elements I am trying to interact with are the drop downs that define the an order's properties. Your method doesn't set the values of those dropdowns (it only changes them cosmetically).

Comment: Sean your response above sounds like you expect an event to be fired. How about calling that directly from your script instead of relaying on events?

Answer (score 0):

you can select an option by doing this

```js
function selectItemInDropdownList(selectElement, ov) {
  const optionToSelect = '' + ov
  const options = selectElement.getElementsByTagName('option')
  for (const optionEle of options) {
    if (optionToSelect === optionEle.innerText || optionToSelect === optionEle.value) {
      optionEle.selected = true // selects this option
      return true
    }
  }
  return false // failed
}

/*
const dropdownEle = document.getElementById('whatever')
const status = selectItemInDropdownList(dropdownEle, "WHAT") 
console.log(status ? 'success' : 'failed')
*/
```

I think main issue is its a popup form and the `select` element 'may' not be available in DOM tree at first. so make sure to call this function when its available.

Comment: As I mention in my question - I need to set the state of the page, this doesn't set the state of the page.

Comment: what do you mean by "state of the page" and where have you mentioned it because i cant find it question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well in 2022. No jQuery is used.

Auto expand select options in element `cb`:

```
cb.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true }))
```

Input focus on element `cb`  (tested on Safari), watch the compatibility note on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus):

```
cb.focus()
```

Below are the working solution for you to copy and run on a browser. (Since input focus feature is failed to run in the code snippet here, while the feature auto expand the select options still works.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="select-1">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>

    <input id="input-1" type="text"/> 

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            const select = document.getElementById('select-1');
            const input = document.getElementById('input-1');

            input.focus();
            setTimeout(function() {
                select.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true }));
            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I mention in my question - I need to set the state of the page. Your code only sets the value of an option whose state is not controlled by backbone / react etc.

Comment: Noted, let’s clarify. Is that you need a pure javascript solution or other else?

Comment: My current solution is missing a handle change and storing e.target.value to global window, as a workaround of page state, isn’t it?