# Script to click 3 buttons on a webpage

Tags: javascript, button, browser, click, refresh

I have this problem I am trying to solve so I dont have to sit in front of the computer all day. The problem I have is I have to be among the first 6 to sign up on new objects that come in daily. It involves three clicks at different places on the webpage, the first is an 'expand button', and then comes the second button (which can be located a bit randomly vertically, but at the same spot horizontally) which is the signup button and finally the third button which asks to confirm. The last button is located to the left of the second button and at a fixed distance.

After this the browser should again load the page where the objects arrive and it's rinse repeat. If there is no new object I want the script to do nothing and just refresh the page once every minute or so.

So my question is areound the doability of this? And where the best place would be to start and what to look for? At first I thought it'd be piece of cake but now I am not so sure naymore....

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: It sounds very doable, though you probably won't get someone to write the code here. What you want is greasemonkey scripts, just searching for it here and in google will get you the answer. Take this SO question for starters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252701/how-do-i-click-on-this-button-with-greasemonkey?lq=1

Comment: Will make sure to check this out! Would you have a time estimate on this for someone with limited (as in a 3 java courses at uni) coding experience? Thanks